# Close Docker container ran with -t

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cloud9

I'm pretty new to Docker and am running it via AWS Cloud9 to mess around with it so I can learn more before I tackle a big project. I was practicing editing a Dockerfile and then building and running it. I accidentally did "docker run -t" instead of -it and am now stuck. I have looked up the meaning of a docker run with -t but cannot seem to figure out how to close the container. I have tried exit, control c + d, control d, and stop but after typing anything in the command line it goes blank waiting for an echo. I would really appreciate some assistance to get the container closed.

The full command I ran was "docker run -t myffmpeg" but the solution for me was to open a new terminal window and doing a "docker container prune"

Comment: You don't "close" containers generally; they're wrappers around some single process, so you need to cause that process to exit (or `docker stop` the container).  Can you provide a [mcve], including the Dockerfile for your image and the complete `docker run` command that started the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the main question, the solution for me was to open a new terminal window and doing a "docker container prune"